# Date time for time zones

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

In C#

`DateTime.Now.Day` Vs. `DateTime.Now.Date.Day` => What is the actual difference?

For say, when i am PST zone say 8 PM - 08/26, when I call

```
DateTime.Now.Day //26
DateTime.Now.Date.Day //26
```

For say, when i am EST zone say 8 PM - 08/26, when i call

```
DateTime.Now.Day //27
DateTime.Now.Date.Day //27
```

I am trying to get Day from datetime or a date, so that I want to use a day which can be consistent in any PST/EST/CST time zones, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference (see the [`DateTime Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) documentation). The `.Date` identifier simply strips out the time information from the `DateTime` object you're working with.

If you want consistent time, use UTC time, and the [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks,DateTime.Now -> Will it give server's time if that piece of code is coming from server side code, for say if the server is in PST zone, will it give PST date time value & vice versa for EST?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` gives the current computer/system time of the server in whatever timezone it's in, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: use [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx).

Long answer:

Break it down in terms of expressions and the type system:

`DateTime` is a value type with a few static members. One of those members is `Now`.  The static `Now` property returns an instance of a `DateTime` struct populated with the value of the current time.  But it's still a DateTime type instance.

The `Date` member is available to instances of the `DateTime` type, and returns a new DateTime instance with the values for the time component zero'd out.  But it's *still* just a DateTime type instance.

The `Day` member is available to instances of the `DateTime` type, and returns an integer for the current day of the month.

You want to know, first of all, if there is a difference between `DateTime.Now.Date.Day` and `DateTime.Now.Day`.  Logically, you would think there is none, but I do want to point out one thing on the `Now` property: it's not magic. Code runs, and therfore time passes, after you access the `Now` property and while executing the `.Date.Day` expression.  During that time, the original `Now` value used becomes stale.  This expression is very fast and hardly takes any time at all — but it's not zero.  If you're not careful, you could be creating a race condition.

Secondly, you want to know about timezones and getting consistent dates. The trick here is whether you really care only about the US timezones listed and whether you'll have any times near midnight in any zone.  But really the best option is to look at another member of the DateTime data type: it's `.UtcNow` property. This will return the same value regardless of what timezone you are in.  You can use it to evaluate a time that will consistent across all your timezones.